# Problem in switching from PL/SQL Developer to SQL Developer

Tags: database

I want to become Ubuntu user, but **SQL Developer** is not comfortable enough for me. Main problem for me is that when I query data with **select** statemant and the result is displayed it is not possible to edit data directly (this feature is in **PL\SQL Developer**). Does there exist solution for this: directly to edit queried data.

Comment: Are we talking about simple queries  ?

Comment: no, not simple. of course from one table but with complicated/long where part

Answer (score 3):

If the queries are simple, just Click on `Views` -> `Connections`. Navigate to your desired  table and double click on it. From this window you can edit the data.

FWIW PL/SQL Developer runs fine on WINE as well.

Comment: I've tried WINE but it doesn't work as well as in windows. If I have large <b>where</b> then it is not convenient to query data from double click on table...

Comment: You can try Toad freeware.